# Passing data from two Models into one View via ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, entity

I'm trying to pass data from 2 models into a single view model, so i can view the contents of both data tables, trying to do this in my controller action:

```
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                var cards = _context.Cards.Single(c => c.Id == id);

                var decks = _context.Cards.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);

                var viewModels = (from m in cards.Deck
                    join r in decks on m.Card.id equals r.CoachId
                    select new DeckCardViewModel()
                    {
                        Card.Id= m.Id,
                        Deck.Id = r.Id
                    }).ToList();

            }
```

My Viewmodel:

```
 public class DeckCardViewModel
    {
        public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
        public List<Deck> Decks { get; set; }
    }
```

My Models:

```
 public class Card
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Atk { get; set; }
        public int? Def { get; set; }
        public string Desc {get; set;}
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public virtual List<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Deck> Deck { get; set; }


    }

 public class Deck
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Card")]
        public virtual List<Card> Card { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model YGOBuilder.Models.ViewModels;


    <div>
        <h4>Card</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.Card_Images)
            {

                <dd>
                    <img src=@item.image_url height="300" width="200" style="margin: 2px">
                </dd>

            }


        </dl>


        <h1>Your Decks</h1>

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>

        </dl>


    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

What I'm trying to do in my view, is print details of a single Card, and then print a list of all available decks in my database. I appear to be trying and failing to gather the data from the database and then partitioning that data

Comment: What isn't working, it's not clear. `I appear to be trying and failing to gather the data from the database and then partitioning that data`, where in the code are you doing this?

Comment: Surely the `new DeckCardViewModel()` in your first snippet doesn't build? `DeckCardViewModel` doesn't have a `Card` member. I think your close, but instead of trying to assign the `Card.Id` you need to build up a `Card` instance and add it to the `Cards` collection (don't forget to initialize the list!).

Comment: Try following : List<DeckCardViewModel>  results = _context.Cards.SelectMany(m => m.Card_Images.Select(r => new DeckCardViewModel()
                    {
                        Card.Id = m.Id,
                        Deck.Id = r.Id
                    })).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng - that wouldn't work, see my comment above. `Card` doesn't exist (in `DeckCardViewModel`).

Comment: Hi there @jdweng yes it does not build

Comment: @JayMee, im not following what you mean, can you provide a snippet to better explain?

Comment: trued this, but still no joy.  

public ActionResult AddToDeck(int id)
        {


            var viewModel = new DeckCardViewModel
            {
                cards = _context.Cards.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id),
                decks = _context.Decks.ToList
        };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

Comment: Try following. : var results = _context.Cards.SelectMany(m => m.Deck.Select(r => new { Cards = m.Id, Deck_Id = r.id })).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var cards = _context.Cards.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            var decks = _context.Decks.ToList();

            var viewModel = new DeckCardViewModel
            {

               Cards = cards,
               Decks = decks
        };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

This allowed me to print the cards and the decks to the view.